# PYQT : qCombobox displaying Column "Name" but passing Column "ID"

Tags: mysql, pyqt, pyqt4, qcombobox

I've been trying very hard to get this working but so far haven't found the correct route.
I am using pyqt, and I am querying a MySql DataBase, collecting from it a model with all the columns. Until here it's all good..

I've created a combobox that is displaying the correct text using model.setcolumn(1)
What I need now is for this combobox to send on "activated" the relative unique ID of this record, so I am able to create a category relatioship.

What exactly is the best way to do this? I feel I've arrived to a dead end, any help would be appreciated.

Best,
Cris

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be sub-classing `QComboBox`. You can't override the `activated` signal but you can create a custom signal that will also be emitted with ID whenever `activated` is emitted. And you can connect to this signal and do your stuff. It will be something like this:

```py
class MyComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    activatedId = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int) #correct this if your ID is not an int

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.activated.connect(self.sendId)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def sendId(self, index):
        model = self.model()
        uniqueIdColumn = 0 # if ID is elsewhere adjust
        uniqueId = model.data(model.createIndex(index,uniqueIdColumn,0),QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        self.activatedId.emit(uniqueId)
```

**Edit**
Here is a similar version without Signals. This will return `uniqueId` whenever you call `sendId` with an `index` of the combobox.

```
class MyComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

    def sendId(self, index):
        model = self.model()
        uniqueIdColumn = 0 # if ID is elsewhere adjust
        uniqueId = model.data(model.createIndex(index,uniqueIdColumn,0),QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        return uniqueId
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for you reply, I really appreciate this.. I've implemented this class in my code and I am calling MyComboBox.sendId(index) from my activated function, however I am not getting a Unique Id back. I think there could be something wrong with uniqueId = model.data(model.cre....  I am printing uniqueId but I am not getting my Id number... I am trying this also just after declaring the model, to see if it will return a value, but it's not doing it (replacing with numbers index, etc). Any ideas?

Comment: @user1028826: I thought, you meant a Signal/Slot relationship. If you are looking for a regular function/method, see my edit.

Comment: thanks again Avaris for your reply. Doing it this way seems a bit simpler to start with, but I am not getting a value when I print "uniqueID", if I a print I get <PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant object at 0x0000000003E542B8>. Isnt there a simpler way of getting a single field from a table or Record?

Comment: @user1028826: That is because in Python 2.x, PyQt returns Qt Type variables. You can [change this behavior](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/incompatible_apis.html) by adapting v2 API of types. Then all those return values will be regular Python types. Or just use any of the [appropriate](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qvariant.html) `to*` functions of `QVariant`. I believe `return uniqueId.toInt()` would do the trick (Of course, I'm assuming your ID's are integer. If not use the function that fits). But I'd recommend using the v2 API way.

Comment: Thanks so much again, I would have never got there without you tell me this last bit about v2 API. I am really great full for your help.

Comment: Hi, coming back to this example.. I am now trying to connect to the signal, based on the first example. How can I connect to the signal once the signal is emitted?

Comment: @user1028826: It is the same as normal signals. Just have a method that can receive your ID (say `self.doSomethingWithId`) and connect signal using `self.myComboBoxInstance.sendId.connect(self.doSomethingWithId)`.